# Can I use reinforcement learning in tensorflowjs?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, tensorflowjs

I'm doing a project at the moment which would require tensorflowjs to create a neural network that learns from reinforcement learning algorithms. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!

There are many examples of this online. 
I would recommend you to take a look at https://github.com/BeTomorrow/ReImproveJS a reinforcement learning framework made using tfjs.

Example using ReImproveJS can be found here: https://gist.github.com/RGBKnights/756b5f51465cc22d0ca39205979ad2a1

Also another example of applied tfjs is found here: https://www.metacar-project.com/

Another example of DQN applied to snake in tfjs, with instructions on how to run the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/tree/master/snake-dqn

Comment: Reimprove appears to be abandoned? Per one of the replies to an open issue.

Comment: It's also not compatible with the latest tensorflow

Comment: Unfortunately, ReImproveJS - This repository is deprecated.